# Formatting in PrintWriter

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I am reading this tutorial:
[link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/printwriter.html)

That get result I am trying to invoke this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        writer.print(true);
        writer.print((int) 123);
        writer.print((float) 123.456);

        writer.printf(Locale.UK, "Text + data: %1$", 123); //cause of exception

        writer.close();
    }
```

I am get exception:`java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '1'`

Is it my mistake or tutorial author?

Comment: Which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Have you tried without %d instead of %1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the way the string is formatted -
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

It seems that `1$` indicates which argument but you still need a conversion after that - `%1$d`

Comment: Thus tutorial mistake

Comment: yup, its a typo in the tutorial.